# What is the combinatorics meaning of the generating function for Legendre polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions, generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

I know the generating function has been a super useful tool when finding the Legendre polynomials (or other special functions), or even used to estimate the static electric potential. In the Physics textbook, it is directly given as:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2ht+h^2}}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty h^iP_i(t)$$
I am super confused after taking a Combinatorics course cause I can't find a word relevent to this in my textbook, but I am quite sure there must be some combinatorics argument underlies any generating function.

(p.s. first time asking question here, sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 1):

I like to view at this from a historical location:

see [Why do the Legendre Polynomials have these coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513965/why-do-the-legendre-polynomials-have-these-coefficients/3527598#3527598)

So - for me the generating function is clear and the way that it is a sum of polynomial functions, for me is more the definition of the Legendre polynomials - which then are subject to very nice recurrence, integral and differential equations.